# Did consciousness always exist?

Tags: reference-request, consciousness, mind-body

Speaking of Stuart Hameroff and Sir Roger Penrose:

> "Both of them now believe that consciousness, as the interplay of
>   fine-scale quantum events, may have always existed in the universe." 
>   - Jonathan Bricklin  https://www.scienceandnonduality.com/article/science-and-consciousness-just-wed-should-this-union-be-annulled

Is there any publication where either of them treat this idea?
Any secondary sources or critiques?

Comment: penrose believes what? cool ha

Comment: how is he defining "consciousness" (for the lay person)?

Comment: @another_name What I've found so far is more about the How? than the What? I've read Shadows of the Mind by Penrose a long time ago, and don't remember that he gave a novel definition of consciousness. Hopefully if the requested publications exist it will shed some light.

Comment: Thanks @JohnForkosh, I'm looking specifically for something by Hamerhoff and/or Penrose. But if their view really are as described in the article, it would certainly be reminiscent of panpsychism.

Comment: See their recent review [Consciousness in the universe: A review of the ‘Orch OR’ theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571064513001188). The quote is a stretch based on the author's wishful thinking. What they write is more reminiscent of Whitehead's "experience":"*Each such event would lack cognition or any non-computational influence, but would be associated with an undifferentiated ‘proto-conscious’ experience, one without information or meaning.*"

Comment: @Conifold Thought as much. Do you know if they took a position on _when_ "information or meaning" became categorical?

Comment: "*Central nervous systems consisting of approximately 300 neurons, such as those present in tiny worms and urchins at  the early  Cambrian  evolutionary  explosion  540  million  years  ago,  theoretically  had  sufficient  microtubules  to reach τ under one minute, and it might thus be just feasible for them to make use of Orch OR. Accordingly, one might speculate that the onset of Orch OR and primitive consciousness, albeit exceedingly slow and simple but still with useful conscious moments, precipitated the accelerated evolution of the Cambrian explosion.*"

Comment: I don't know of any texts where they explain their idea. They seem to be arguing for the Perennial view without referring to it, which leaves them with a clunky metaphysical conjecture but no explanatory theory. It's an approach to the issues I cannot understand and it does not seem scientific.They seem to be few millennia behind the curve.   .  .  .

Comment: @PeterJ The quoted comment seemed out of step with what I knew of Penrose, hence the question. The link, by Conifold, gives an overview of the state of the Hamerhoff-Penrose theory of consciousness, and no indication that they would venture beyond purely scientific interests. On the other hand: see answer by Frank.

Comment: @christo183 - I didn't mean to suggest they were going beyond scientific interests  but rather that their approach is not scientific. It's not something that needs discussing here, but it may partly explain the scarcity of 'treatment' the OP asks about.     .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stuart Hameroff's site "Quantum Consciousness" may provide a source of [publications](https://www.quantumconsciousness.org/content/orch-or-quantum) related to this topic. In the [overview](https://www.quantumconsciousness.org/content/overview-sh) Hameroff writes:

> On the other hand, spiritual and contemplative traditions, and some scientists and philosophers consider consciousness to be intrinsic, ‘woven into the fabric of the universe’. In these views, conscious precursors and Platonic forms preceded biology, existing all along in the fine scale structure of reality.

That view would suggest "conscious precursors" were always present, preceding biology. The list of publications and research posted on this site would likely provide the most relevant details clarifying and supporting this position.

---

Hameroff, S. Overview. Retrieved on September 12, 2019 from *Quantum Consciousness* at https://www.quantumconsciousness.org/content/overview-sh

Comment: Didn't know Plato did QM! Time after all is not a member of the platonic realm 

Comment: @Rusi As I understand this, which might be incorrect, Plato would have just recognized these conscious precursors as forms. I see this as a kind of panpsychism that would explain (away?) Platonic forms.

Comment: @Rusi The Hamerhoff-Penrose theory of consciousness is a material monist conception. Relying on a critical number of entangled "Objective Reduction" events to produce "proto-conscious" moments, as such it does not rely on biology to be the carrier of consciousness (biology merely found ways to concentrate material in a way that allows for _Orchestrated_ OR). Considering the sheer amount matter involved in the universe relative to a human brain, it is easy to imagine that something like a Platonic TREE must have been encoded in matter long before Biology.

Comment: @Rusi I don't think their usage of the term "Forms" quite match how Plato had it, but it does seem to vindicate (once again) Plato's insight.